# How to strip symbols out of a framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, compilation, building

I have a swift application that includes a framework of object files (.o files) compiled from objective - c sources, and the respective headers.  In the final release executable the symbols of the library are still present.  I've tried removing them by setting "Deployment Post Processing", "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy", "Strip Linked Product", "Strip Swift Symbols", and "Dead Code Stripping" all to YES, but the symbols of the libraries remain in the executable.

Ideas?

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/neonichu/1662881